Volume dependence on quantization of the electromagnetic field
I'm studying a non-additive formalism where volume dependencies play a crucial role, and I am particularly interested in applying these models to electromagnetic radiation, which has a well-defined quantization structure.
In particular, I am focusing on the density of states within the canonical quantization method, which is given by:
$$
g(\mathbf{k}) = \frac{\omega^2 V}{8\pi^3 c^3} d\omega \sin \theta \, d\theta \, d\phi,
$$
where $V$ represents the "quantization volume."
My question is: does this volume refer to an arbitrary choice, or is it constrained? Specifically, could this volume range from something as small as a QED cavity to as large as the volume encompassing blackbody radiation in the universe?
Thank you.

That would depend entirely on context. From where do you draw that equation? If it doesn’t say so, knowing what text it is might at least help determine what the particular meaning of $V$ is.

@controlgroup The context involves the density of states of a monochromatic electromagnetic wave in a cavity of volume $V$, as found in "Quantum Statistical Properties of Radiation by Louisell" (1973), pp. 250-251. This formulation appears to be very general, applying to essentially any volume in space.
